# PHP handler type for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, database-performance

I have a vps server (with Plesk Onyx) in which I have to install Wordpress, and I don't know which php manager is better. The site has a large number of entries, greater than 10,000. So I have to choose between these PHP handlers.

[Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPayv.png)

If the information is useful, these are the statistics of my vps:

- vCPU: 2 core
- RAM : 2 GB
- SSD: 40 GB
- Multi-Core Geekbench Score: 991
- Bandwidth: 2 TB
- Inode limit: 2 621 440
- Dedicated IP Suport IPv4/IPv6
- 100 Mb/s network
- Total Access Root

Currently the wordpress theme asks for these requirements:
[Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvHZU.png)

Which PHP handler provides the **best** performance?

I have been using FPM application served by ngine. I understand that the connection that wordpress makes to the database should be a single one and when reviewing phpmyadmin it seems to be like that. But the CPU is permanently at 100% and I can't get it to go down. I removed plugins and placed cache, also cloudflare to handle the dangerous traffic, however with 500 users per hour the site destroys the database.

Comment: Did you try switching between them to see if you noticed a difference? Apache vs Nginx is a fairly significant change, and you'd want to make sure you have the appropriate rules in place to support that. I think the dedicated vs others has to do with creating PHP services per-site, so if you only have a single site it doesn't matter. Otherwise you've just got FastCGI vs FPM which you can read about here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4526242/231316

Comment: Nginx and fpm is a good choice, but you need to adjust settings. Add proxy_cache rules to nginx, add redis cache for queries.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx and fpm. Hands down. If you can get the open litespeed server, that'll be even better for WordPress.

2GiB of RAM means you should use MariaDb 6 or better: those versions are smarter about using RAM efficiently, and 2GiB is constrained-RAM provisioning.